# Calculate the degree of $F(\alpha)$ over $F(\alpha^4/4\alpha^3 - 1)$.

Tags: field-theory

Let $F$ be a field and $\alpha$ a transcendental element of some extension. Calculate the degree of $F(\alpha)$ over $F(\alpha^4/4\alpha^3 - 1)$.

This exercise is from Allan Clark's Elements of Abstract Algebra. Unfortunately, it seems that the ebook version is kinda poorly done, as the problem was probably meant to have $F(\alpha^4/(4\alpha^3 - 1))$ in place of the original extension. I believe this because the two given fields seem trivially isomorphic, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Anyway, if this is the case, it seems really difficult to find a basis for the second field.

Comment: $\pi$ is transcendental but $\mathbb Q(\pi)$ still has degree 2 over $\mathbb Q(\pi^2)$.

Comment: @Arkady Right, it clearly doesn't work that way then. It was an optimistic approach anyway. Presumably it really is necessary to find a basis for the field then?

Comment: Write $\beta=\alpha^4/(4\alpha^3-1)$ so that $\alpha$ is a root of $x^4-4x^3\beta+\beta\in F(\beta) [x] $. This gives you some information on degree of $F(\alpha) $ over $F(\beta) $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For any non-zero element $x$, the fields $F(x)$ and $F(1/x)$ are equal because well, they are both fields. Use this to simplify your problem.